# Validating parameters to create a class, parameters created in the controller arn't being added.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, strong-parameters

I create a class that takes two input parameters from the user, these input parameters are then used to create five others, the problem is that the five others don't show up when I check my validated paramaters only the first ones.

I know that all of the new parameters are added to the params but they don't show up in the model time_delta_params hash when I check what's in it only the first two. Thanks for any help!

**My create method for the controller**

```
  def create
    # XXX Add these columns to the model and populate them
    # finalRating, positiveTweets, negativeTweets, neutralTweets, totalTweets
    tweetRatings = {:finalRating => 0, :positiveTweets => 0, :negativeTweets => 0, :neutralTweets => 0} 
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_id])
    tweets = getTweets(@stock.hashtag, time_delta_params[:start], time_delta_params[:length].to_i)
    tweets.each do |tweet|
      case processTweet(tweet)
        when 1
          tweetRatings[:positiveTweets]  += 1
          tweetRatings[:finalRating]     += 1
        when -1
          tweetRatings[:negativeTweets]  += 1
          tweetRatings[:finalRating]     -= 1
        else 
          tweetRatings[:neutralTweets]   += 1
      end
    end

    params[:final]      = tweetRatings[:finalRating]
    params[:positive]   = tweetRatings[:positiveTweets]
    params[:negative]   = tweetRatings[:negativeTweets]
    params[:neutral]    = tweetRatings[:neutralTweets]
    params[:total]      = tweets.count
    # printSomthingToRender(time_delta_params)
    @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.create(time_delta_params)
    redirect_to stock_path(@stock)
  end
```

**My validation:**

```
def time_delta_params
      params.require(:time_delta).permit(
        :start, 
        :length,
        :final, 
        :positive, 
        :negative, 
        :neutral, 
        :total
        )
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `create` with the `time_delta_params` that isn't going to contain the `tweetRatings` data. You would need to do something like `params['time_delta'][:final] = tweetRating[:finalRating]`.  You could also call create and create your hash there or rename the values in the `tweetRatings` hash to match what is in the model.

Comment: This worked perfect thanks this makes sense too it needed to be on the time delta's params.

Answer (score 1):

You are not merging the additional parameters into the `time_delta` hash, but straight to the top level of `params`.  `time_delta` is a hash within `params`.

You need to do something like:

```
params[:time_delta].merge!(final:    tweetRatings[:finalRating],
                           positive: tweetRatings[:positiveTweets],
                           negative: tweetRatings[:negativeTweets],
                           neutral:  tweetRatings[:neutralTweets],
                           total:    tweets.count)
```

Comment: I said pretty much the same thing, your code is much more concise.